# Isolatedness of critical points of Morse functions

Tags: analysis, differential-topology

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb R$ is a  [Morse function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory#Fundamental_theorems) , i.e. is smooth and all its critical points are non-degenerate . Intuitively, why all the critical points of $f$ happen to be isolated? How would you prove this without mentioning manifolds ?(Morse theory has applications in classifying manifolds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Morse lemma, any non-degenerate critical point is locally on the form $$ (x_1, \dots, x_n) \mapsto -x_1^2 + \dots - x_r^2 + x_{r+1}^2 + \dots + x_{n}^2$$ where $r$ is the number of negative eigenvalues of the Hessian matrix. It's clear that $0$ is the only critical point in a small neighbourhood.

You don't need manifold, just implicit function theorem and Hadamard's lemma are enough, for example looks [here](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2010/REUPapers/Hua.pdf) (don't be misguided by the title, the proof actually does not use any manifold !)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of Morse lemma. Why is the $\{p: f'(p)=0, f''(p)\not =0\}$  discrete? Obvious implication is that on a closed finite interval we have only finitely many n-d critical points? But why?

Comment: The function that I wrote and which appears in Morse lemma has only a single critical point. So if $p$ is a critical point of $f$, by Morse lemma it has a neighbourhood where $f$ can be written on this form. It follows that there is a neighbourhood of $p$ so that $p$ is the only critical point. This is the definition of a discrete set.